# promise keep return the empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, promise

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        detailWallet: [],
        user: [],
        historia: [],
        namaPertama: [],
        namaKirim: [],
    
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getDetailAPI();
    this.getDetailPlaceAPI();
    this.getHistoria();
}

getNameAPI = () => {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    return new Promise(resolve => {          
        axios.get(`/wallet/user/${id}`)
        .then((result) => {
            resolve(
                this.setState({
                    namaPertama: result.data.data.content[0].user.firstName
                })
            )
        })
    });
}

getHistoria = () => {
    console.log(this.getNameAPI())
    Promise.all([this.getNameAPI()])
    .then(([result]) => {
        this.setState({
            namaKirim: result
        })
    })
    axios.get(`/wallet/type/6?q=`)
    .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
            historia: result.data.data.content
        })
    })
}
```

so i make a function that have a method get inside a promise, and when i console.log it in getHistoria, the promise give me an empty array..

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? i just learning about the promise so i still don't really know about it, thank you..

Comment: `Promise.all([this.getNameAPI()]).then(...)` - Why the unnecessary `Promise.all()` call? Just do `this.getNameAPI().then(...)`

Comment: But then reintroduce `Promise.all()` to aggregate the two promises returned by `this.getNameAPI()` and `axios.get()`. And return the aggregated promise.

Comment: @Andreas i try it, but nothing change, the result still give me an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the result of `setState`, I don't think setState is returning anything. Besides, setState is asynchronous, so you won't have the result of the updated state if you loged the state just after.

Just set the state with setState and return some value.

EDIT:

```
getNameAPI = () => {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    return new Promise(resolve => {          
        axios.get(`/wallet/user/${id}`)
        .then((result) => {
          let value =  result.data.data.content[0].user.firstName;
          this.setState({ namaPertama: value})
          resolve(value)
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, can u show me how to do that? i still cannot figure out about it

Comment: The resolve keyword is like a return statement but for promise, it indicates if Promise is done or not (reject). So the value u are passing to resolve will be the value the promise is returning. But here you are passing to resolve, the result of this.setState, and setState is not returning anything, it just set the state. See EDIT of my post